# How to get ordered result on a datatable in c#

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I have a problem to run a query on a `DataTable` in order to get `DataRow` with a a field set to a specific value and ascendent ordererd on another field.

```
 DataTable dt = myDataset.Tables["MyTable"];
 DataRow[] foundRows = dt.Select("Done > 0", "Position ASC");
```

The `Position` field can be set to a negative value (-1): in this case that row is not considered and the query returns results which have Position = 0,1,2,....

Can someone help me?
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that the rows with `Done > 0` has `position  = -1` in the table?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes, the datatable is obtained from a Dataset loaded from a XML file. Each node, among children's nodes, also has the node `poistion`. There is a node with the `position` set to the -1 value

Comment: Does it have `Done > 0` ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes it has `Done` = 1

Comment: Then the probable reason could be the data type of position column. If it is string then it will not sort the values of it as numbers.